# First GridView dissapears when binding a second GridView in code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a problem with a couple of gridviews that are filled from the code behind.
When I fill and databind GridView1 on it's own it works fine.
I then added the code to fill and bind GridView2 which displays but GridView1 dissapears completely.
If I comment out GridView2.DataBind() then GridView1 then appears again.
I can't work out what is going on.

Incidentaly if I change GridView2 for a DropDownList or a CheckBoxList then the same problem occurs, but if I change it for a ListBox then GridView1 appears.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Int32 chaID = 20;
    Int32 slots = 14;

    String ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["horizonConnectionString"].ToString();
    String selectSQL = "SELECT chassis.ChassisName, srv.ChassisPosition, srv.ServerName, srv.ChassisID, srv.LocationID, chassis.LocationID AS ChaLocationID FROM srv INNER JOIN chassis ON srv.ChassisID = chassis.ChassisID WHERE (srv.ChassisID = '" + chaID + "') ORDER BY chassis.ChassisName, srv.ChassisPosition";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    DataView dv = new DataView();

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(selectSQL, con);
        sda.Fill(dt2);
        dv = dt2.DefaultView;


    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }


    try
    {

        int searchIndex;
        dv.Sort = "ChassisPosition";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Bay", typeof(Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Server", typeof(String)));

        for (int i = 0; i <= slots - 1; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = i + 1;

            searchIndex = dv.Find(i + 1);

            if (searchIndex != -1)
            {
                dr[1] = dv[searchIndex][2].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                dr[1] = "-----";

            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }


        ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["horizonConnectionString"].ToString();

        selectSQL = "SELECT [ServerName], [ServerID], [FarmName], [LMG] FROM [srv] ORDER BY [ServerName]";
        con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();


        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(selectSQL, con);
            sda.Fill(dt3);

            this.GridView2.DataSource = dt3;
            GridView2.DataBind();


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no reason that binding some controls should cause this, which would indicate that you have a layout problem. I would suggest that you edit your question and add the markup from your aspx file as well - it is likely that when grid2 has data (and therefore some size) it is covering grid1 or pushing it somewhere it shouldn't be.

Comment: please put a break point on the page load event ,, and trace the datasource (data tables of GV1, and GV2),and tell me is it empty or has data , or some error happens and make exception but because your ,`try and catch` u can't recognize it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same instance of **SqlDataAdapter** for two connections at the same time.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
```

the **SqlDataAdapter** object has been named **"sda"** twice in "page_load" method.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(selectSQL, con);
```

SqlDataAdapter "sda" is already binding to GridView1. this data binding will be lost if U change or re-assign this object.

Comment: I changed the name of the second SqlDataAdapter but it still does the same thing. I also tried to use a standard SqlDataSource bound to the second GridView instead of doing it in code but that was the same too (and GridView2 does not display all the records either it stops after 24 records and seems to go off the page).